# Populating an IF Statement Dynamically from Lists C#

Tags: c#, list, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to populate this if statement dynamically so that I dont have to continue adding else if's to it when I add more items to the list.
I'm sure I could do it with nested foreach statements, I just not sure how to do it properly.

```
        private List<string> uriList = new List<string>();
        private List<string> titleList = new List<string>();

                    if (item.Text == titleList[0])
                    {
                        YTPlayer(uriList[0].ToString());
                    }
                    else if (item.Text == titleList[1])
                    {
                        YTPlayer(uriList[1].ToString());
                    }
                    else if (item.Text == titleList[2])
                    {
                        YTPlayer(uriList[2].ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < titleList.count(); i++) 
{
  if (item.Text == titleList[i])
  {
      YTPlayer(uriList[i].ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: This actually worked for me, the previous answer I selected would leave me with index out of range errors. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need just an integer.

```
int i = 0
foreach (var item in items)
{
        if (item.Text == titleList[i])
        {
            YTPlayer(uriList[i].ToString());
            break;
        }
        i++;     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution to that would be adding a `Dictionary<string, Action>()` and initialize behaviors depending on the input. That would play the role of a dispatcher. It's movable and it scales easily

Answer (score 1):

You should use a for loop over `titleList`

```
private List<string> uriList = new List<string>();
private List<string> titleList = new List<string>();

    for (var i = 0; i < titleList.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (item.Text == titleList[i])
        {
            YTPlayer(uriList[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
```

This will let you use any size list.

Also, there's no need to call `ToString()` on a `string`.

You could also use `IndexOf` too

```
    var i = titleList.IndexOf(item.Text);
    if (i != -1)
        YTPlayer(uriList[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list methods instead. Also you don't need `.ToString()` for `uriList` as it's a list of strings.

```
if (titleList.Contains(item.Text)) {
    int index = titleList.IndexOf(item.Text);
    YTPlayer(uriList[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
int index = itemList.FindIndex(x => x == item.Text);
if (index >= 0 && index < uriList.Count)
{
   YTPlayer(uriList[index]);
}
else
{
// Your else
}
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-5.0